# How to do a point plot in R with three groups of data?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I'm trying to plot this data frame in a point-plot, and I want to divide the data in three different groups according to the size with three different colours:

```
Size    pH
0,001   4,308
0,001   4,269
0,001   4,273
0,5     4,436
0,5     4,406
1,5     4,384
1,5     4,385
```

Comment: what code have you tried? here is a great ggplot2 intro from Harvard http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and show us what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)

pH <- runif(18, 1, 7)    
dd <- data.frame(pH, size = c(0.001, 0.5, 1.5))

xyplot(pH ~ seq_along(pH), groups = size, data = dd, auto.key = TRUE)
```

[image]